# Teradata ODBC connection

Tags: odbc, teradata

I am trying to run a stored procedure stored in Teradata database using python script. Teradata ODBC is connected in 'Teradata' mode. Still I am getting the following error:

3932 :Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement

The Stored procedure does not have 'ET' between DML and DDL in my stored procedure.

I do not have access to modify the stored procedure.
When I call th eprocedure in SQL Editor, it runs absolutely fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciatd.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like Python adds a `BT` before submitting the `CALL`, thus all SQL within the SP will be considered part of a single transaction and you can't mix DDL&DML within a transaction...

Comment: Thank you Dnoeth. Is there any solution for this without modifying SP?

Comment: You might try submitting `ET;` first followed by the `CALL`.

Comment: I tried two different things:
1. '''call sp; ET;''' 
On this I got an error as 'CALL cannot be submitted in multi-statement request'

2. '''call ET; SP;'''
Error as 'Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between the 'call' keyword and the 'ET' keyword.'

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Must be two seperate statements: `ET;` and then `CALL...`, if this is also failing Phyton automatically adds `BT;` whenever a transaction is commited. Don't know if this a setting which can be changed.

Comment: With this option as well, I am getting the same error as previous;

CALL cannot be submitted in multi-statement request.

Comment: This must be a Phyton setting...

Comment: Any idea about what could be the possible files to check in python?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't work with Python

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help.